have gradient scale (zoom) in a map, without a box
I want to create a map. The center should be in a higher scale with the borders in a wider scale. The aim is to visualize the living locations of a marriage couple till there meeting. The problem is I need to visualze locations worlde wide and a bunch in one country.
I can create the map with a box as usually, which displays a different scale but I have found no solution to create that scale "worb".
